# How to convert any expression into list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have simple question. I want to learn how to write any `expression`  into `list comprehension` of python.

Here's the minimal code i want to convert into `list

```
words = ['I', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'n', "'", 't',' ']
temp = ""
templist = []
for i in words:
    if i == " ":
        templist.append(temp)
        temp = ""
    else:
        temp += i
```

at the end `templist` will have :

```
['I', "don't"]
```

Is there anyway I can do it in `list comprehension`

Comment: `''.join(words).split()`

Comment: In the general case, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list-comprehension with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

out = ["".join(g) for v, g in groupby(words, " ".__eq__) if not v]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['I', "don't"]
```

---

Other solution:

```
out = "".join(words).strip().split(" ")
print(out)
```